# Is it possible to link symbol fill colors between different geometry types in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I would like to link symbol colors between two layers of different geometry types (point and polygon). I have tried to save/load style and to copy/paste but I don't think its designed to work that way across geometries.

Specifically, I have a layer of irrigated parcels with a field for the diversion structure code (ditch headgate) that waters that parcel. I also have a ditch point file with an attribute for each ditch number. More than one parcel can be irrigated by a single ditch ID.

The ditches occur at different locations across the landscape are geographically separated from the parcels.

I would like to color the ditch point fill and the label text the same as the parcel they are irrigating so it is possible to visualize where the water source for each parcel is located.

Possible in qgis to dynamically link the point layer fill colors to be identical to the random colors in the polygon layer?

[image: Irrigated parcels colored by ditch ID and ditches in black labeled with ID]

Comment: As far as I know, what you're asking for isn't a feature that exists with random colors. Closest would probably be to symbolize both layers with a categorized style using the same color ramp and a common attribute. If there is one and only one point for each parcel, a point and parcel with the same attribute should end up with the same color.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/383628/88814