# QGIS custom function error when trying to get color of feature on another layer

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-custom-function

In QGIS 3.16.2 (same on 3.16.0) on Win 10, I created a custom function `get_color` to get a feature's color by layer name\id and feature ID as proposed in this answer by @Dror Bogin: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383753/88814

The expression was successfully created as it appears under custom expressions. However, I'm not able to get the function to run - using [this data](https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/OsypCkWMOejvDAl) (project + layers). I try to define the color of the points as the color of the nearest polygon, setting the point's color to data driven override with this expression: `get_color('Buildings',array_first(overlay_nearest('Buildings',$id)))`. This returns an error: `Evaluation error: $id`. See my screenshot: [image]

Using `array_first(overlay_nearest('Buildings',$id))` however works fine, it returns a feature no. So `$id` seems to be a problem together with the custom function `get_color` in my case.

What is wrong - is there some setting I have to change? I restarted QGIS as well as Windows.

That the solution in principle works is demonstrated by @Dror Bogin who used the very same data as me (linked above) on his Win/QGIS 3.16.1 successfully, see his screenshot, where I get the error mentioned:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying it on another Windows machine and playing around with the settings, I found the problem: the color of my polygon was defined as a categorized style with `$id` as the value to create the classes for differenty symbol colors. I changed this to an attribute value `fid`:

[image]

Like this, it works perfectly. On the point layer, the expression still is `get_color('buildings',array_first(overlay_nearest('buildings',$id)))`, thus with `$id`, not with `'fid'`.
For some reason, the custom function had a problem to refer with `$id` to the polygon layer that itself used `$id` to set the color for the features.

As @Dror Bogin mentioned in his post cited above:

> the function currently only supports single, graduated and categorized
> symbol types, and not rule based.

Thus this makes clear why `$id` did not work.

It would be great to see this custom function become part of the official QGIS code as a new expression.

Comment: It's probably possible, but I wrote a relatively basic function that uses the layer's attributes and doesn't even support rule based symbology because of this reason (rules and expressions were a hassle to parse and I wanted to do a quick and dirty function)

Comment: It's quick but not so dirty ;-) OK, that answers also my question - in fact, you mentioned it already in the other comments yesterday. I should have been more attentive.

Comment: Hi @Babel, I had exactly the same experience re using $id (it messes up the colours) as opposed to an attribute defined to have an ID. But I can't work out why. As you say "Thus this makes clear why $id did not work", would you be able to explain a bit more in detail why this is the case? But, or some expected behaviour?

Comment: I'm quite busy right now and the problem appeared more than two and a half years before, so I don't remember the details. Sorry for not being able to give you an answer - maybe someone else will he able to do so.